# Update text file in remote computer by web access?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have Linux machine running web server with php. It contain a text file name 'autorun.conf' - this is a configuration file, see below.

the user can read that file ('autorun.conf')  from his local computer - using some web browser (e.g. google chrome).

what actually happen is that the files is parse and the user can see the current configuration, then the user can update the configuration it and then send it back to the Linux.

i did most parts of the code :
the html file read the file from linux machine ,parse it,show it and let the user change it.

for example the following code read the file into the 'result' string

```
function Button1_onclick() {
    console.log("button click");
    $.get('/autorun.conf', 
        function(result) {
```

after change the configuration the last thing to do is to send the update 'result' string to the server.

i did not see how i can i do it.
i found plenty of file upload plugins that enable me to send multiple file by drag and drop and find simple example with 'form' that enable me to do it.

[The simplest version of ajax (jQuery) to upload just one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454707/the-simplest-version-of-ajax-jquery-to-upload-just-one-file)

but i did not find some simple code that let me send the update string to make it a file in the Linux.

i will be glad to thank for any help.

Nir

this is the html file and below it is the autorun.conf file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// regular expression
// http://regex101.com/

var autorunFile;

function Button1_onclick() {
    console.log("button click");
    $.get('/autorun.conf', 
        function(result) {
            console.log(typeof(result));
            if (result == 'ON') {
                alert('ON');
            } else if (result == 'OFF') {
                alert('OFF');
            } else {
                // find specified model
                autorunFile = result;

                var pattern = /.*model.*/g;
                var line = pattern.exec(result);
                console.log(line[0]);
                pattern = /\".*\"/g;
                var value = pattern.exec(line[0]);
                console.log(value[0]);
                $("#model").val(value[0]);

                // find ip address
                pattern = /.*app_ip.*/g;
                line = pattern.exec(result);
                console.log(line[0]);
                pattern = /\".*\"/g;
                value = pattern.exec(line[0]);
                console.log(value[0]);
                $("#ipAddress").val(value[0]);

                // find all model options
                // the m flag tell to treat each end of line ( and only the end of file)
                // the g tell to find all matches and not only the first one
                pattern = /(.* =$)/gm;   
                //line = pattern.exec(result);
                line = result.match(pattern);     /// note match give al matches in contrary to exec


                // remove two first entries in array
                var found = $.inArray('stop_programs', line) > -1;
                if (found >= 0) {
                    line.splice(found, 2);
                }

                // trim / chop the ' =' from the end of string
                for( i=0 ; i<line.length ; i++) {
                    line[i] = line[i].substring(0, line[i].length -2);
                }


                var selectList = $("#mySelect");   
                for (k = 0; k < line.length; k++)
                    selectList.append("<option value='" + line[k]+ "'>" + line[k] + "</option>");


            }
        }
    );
}

function changeModel() {
    var val = $( "#mySelect option:selected" ).text();
    console.log(val);
    $("#model").val(val);
}

function Button2_onclick() {
    // extract again the 'model' line
    var pattern = /.*model.*/g;
    var line = pattern.exec(autorunFile);
    //console.log(line[0]);
    var newModel = "model = " + $("#model").val();
    //console.log(newModel);
    var autorunFile1 = autorunFile.replace(line[0], newModel);
    //alert(autorunFile1);

    pattern = /.*app_ip.*/g;
    line = pattern.exec(autorunFile1);
    var appIp = "app_ip ="  + $("#ipAddress").val();
    console.log(appIp);
    var autorunFile2 = autorunFile1.replace(line[0], appIp);

    // now it is the big problem, how can i send 'autorunFile2' string to the linux machine


}



</script>
</head>


<body>
<p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>model</td>
        <td><input id="model"></td>
        <td>ip address</td>
        <td><input id="ipAddress"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr/>
      <tr>
        <td/>
        <td><input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" value="Get" /></td>
        <td/>
        <td><input id="Button2" type="button" onclick="return Button2_onclick()" value="Set" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td/>
        <td><select id="mySelect" onchange="changeModel()" ></select></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
</p>



<div id="myDiv"> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the autorun.conf file

```
# Configuration file for AUTORUN

model = "nexus_stated_eth";
app_ip = "192.168.15.110";
debug_mode = "false";
work_dir = "/opt/goji";

stop_programs =
(
    { name = "MBUS_LISTENER"; },
    { name = "ETHERNET_LISTENER"; },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; },
    { name = "HOSTETH_LISTENER"; },
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; }
);

# words to substitute in program arguments:
substitutions =
(
    { key = "BOARDID"; value = "1"; },
    { key = "PLUGINS_PATH"; value = "/tmp/1"; },
    { key = "TECHNICIAN_SOCKET_PORT"; value = "9979"; },
    { key = "NODE_ID"; value = "10"; }
);


nexus_legacy =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS LEGACY";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus"); },
    { name = "ETHERNET_LISTENER"; args = ("-n", "TECHNICIAN", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-p", "TECHNICIAN_SOCKET_PORT" , "-i", "eth0"); }
  )
};

nexus_legacy_cmd =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS LEGACY CMD";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus"); }
  )
};

nexus_stated_mbus =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS STATED MBUS";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "MBUS_LISTENER"; args = ("-p", "NODE_ID", "-n", "HOST", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-d", "/dev/ttyFiq0"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus_stated"); }
  )
};

nexus_stated_eth =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS STATED ETH";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus_stated"); },
    { name = "HOSTETH_LISTENER"; args = ("-n", "HOST", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-p", "TECHNICIAN_SOCKET_PORT" , "-i", "eth0"); }
  )
};

nexus_stated_usb_rj45adaptor =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS STATED USB ETH";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus_stated"); },
    { name = "HOSTETH_LISTENER"; args = ("-n", "HOST", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-p", "TECHNICIAN_SOCKET_PORT" , "-i", "eth1"); }
  )
};

nexus_stated_usb_eth =
{
  message = "STARTING BOARD AS NEXUS STATED ETH";
  programs = 
  (
    { name = "BOSSIMX28"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH"); },
    { name = "GOJIMANAGER"; args = ("-n", "BOARDID", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-g", "98", "-s", "6000000", "-d", "/dev/spidev1.0", "-p", "nexus_stated"); },
    { name = "HOSTETH_LISTENER"; args = ("-n", "HOST", "-f", "PLUGINS_PATH", "-p", "TECHNICIAN_SOCKET_PORT" , "-i", "usb0"); }
  )
};
```

Comment: Despite it collecting an `.conf` file, what would it use to actually execute anything on it? `.conf` itself is not a scripting file.

Comment: Hi, i did not understand the question. this file is a text file with some structure, but as i wrote, i know how to parse it and change it. my issue is that did all the file on a string and my problem now is how to upload the string to the server and create a file from it. i hope that i am more understand ,if not i can put my html/javascript file here

Comment: @nirselickster Apologies, but hopefully I'm able to put this correctly. You need to point the AJAX Call to a scripting language; it would be the scripting language's responsibility to manipulate the contents of that `.conf` file. As far as AJAX and JavaScript is concerned, `.conf` is just a plain text file.

Comment: Hi MackieeE, thanks again for your attention. i am pretty novice in this overwhelming web world and i learn from my missions needs and from appropriates examples. i will look for example that send a string in AJAX toward a server and a PHP script that make it a file (like Juann Strauss sent me below with 'fwrite (.... )). thanks. nir

Answer (score 1):

finally, thanks to your help, i found the solution

i show two different php solutions ( the ajax is also little different)

the first solution is in the html file i add

```
// now it is the big problem, how can i send 'autorunFile2' string to the linux machine
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", // The HTTP request method. 
        url: "uploadString.php", // The URL of the data to fetch. 
        data: autorunFile2, // Don't add any data to the URL. 
        dataType: "text", // Execute the response as a script once we get it. 
        success: function() // Call this function when done.
                        {
                            alert("success");
                        }
                    });
```

this take the string and send it with a HTTP POST command

and in the server side the following php file take the string and save it into a file

```
<?php
file_put_contents('autorun.conf1', file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

in the second solution ( look at 'data' filed)

```
// now it is the big problem, how can i send 'autorunFile2' string to the linux machine
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", // The HTTP request method. 
    url: "uploadString.php", // The URL of the data to fetch. 
    //data: autorunFile2, // Don't add any data to the URL. 
    data:{post: autorunFile2},
    dataType: "text", // Execute the response as a script once we get it. 
    success: function() // Call this function when done.
                    {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                });
```

and the php in the server is

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('autorun.conf1', 'w');
$abc =  $_POST['post'];
fwrite($fp, $abc);
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering.   as i understand this is PHP code ? my problem is in the client side - how i send the data from client to server. thanks

Comment: You can use a simple form post, or AJAX.

Comment: could you please send a link to a suitable example that fit my needs? thanks ahead